# In Django Template: display the sum of calculated variables

Tags: django, templates

right now I wonder if there is a way to show up the sum of variables in a Django-Template. What I mean is, if i have variables of the same kind, is there a template-sided function to add them?

I know, that the "logic" should be normally outside a template, so i wrote a function that does the calculation i want to see in the template:

```
def mission_duration(self):
    duration = self.end - self.begin
    return duration.days
```

and use it in template by {{ mission.mission_duration }} and it works fine.

But if i have several of these variables in a template, is there an easy way to sum their values up and show the result? Right now, the variables are displayed by querying the database going through a for-loop. The result is likely to be displayed outside of the loop elswhere in the template...

or on the other side: how can i put this on model/view.py to solve the problem outside the template? missions are in an oneToMany relationship table to "employees"...and normally data of employees are displayed. so for a model/view solution i have no idea at the moment, how to cycle to all mission entries of an employee to build that desired sum before rendering the template....

-----edit 04/20/2023:

On Base of the first Answer (which made some very good assumptions concerning my app-structure) i changed several things an have now the following code(s):

views.py:

```
...
context = {
...
'missions':Foreign_Missions.objects.filter(employee_id=request.POST['id']).order_by('-begin'),
'total_duration_days':Foreign_Missions.objects.total_duration_days(employee)
}

return render(request, 'show.html', context)
```

in models.py in class "Foreign_Missions":
...

```
objects = Duration_Manager()
```

...

and in managers.py

```
class Duration_Manager(models.Manager):
    def with_duration_days(self):
        return self.annotate(
            duration_days=  ExpressionWrapper(
                (F('end') - F('begin')), output_field=fields.DurationField()
            )
        )

    def total_duration_days(self, employee):
        return self.with_duration_days().filter(employee=employee).aggregate(
            total_duration=Sum('duration_days')
        )['total_duration']
```

Now it works....still have to edit the output-Format of Duration field in "days only"but calculation works correctly now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd probably solve this by having a custom manager for your model, I'm making some assumptions about your model:

```
class MissionManager(models.Manager):
    def with_duration_hours(self):
        return self.annotate(
            duration_hours=ExpressionWrapper(
                (F('end') - F('start')).total_seconds() / 3600, output_field=fields.FloatField()
            )
        )

    def total_duration_hours(self, employee):
        return self.filter(employee=employee).with_duration_hours().aggregate(
            total_duration=Sum('duration_hours')
        )['total_duration']


class Mission(models.Model):
    start = models.DateTimeField()
    end = models.DateTimeField()

    objects = MissionManager()
```

In your view you could then do the following:

```
def your_view(request, employee_id):
    employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=employee_id)
    context["employee_missions"] = Mission.objects.filter(employee=employee).with_duration_hours()
    context["total_duration_hours"] = Mission.objects.total_duration_hours(employee)
```

Comment: Ok got it...most of it, the last line causing trouble is this one:
(F('end') - F('start')).total_seconds() / 3600, output_field=fields.FloatField()

Raising an 'CombinedExpression' object has no attribute 'total_seconds' error :-(